# Why using X in tabularx inserts new line

Tags: line-breaking, tabularx

Why newline is inserted in the first row and why `\noindent` fixes it in the second row?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX lX}
        \rowcolor{gray}
        cell1 & \color{white}{cell2} \\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{gray}
        cell1 & \noindent\color{white}{cell2} \\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No problem when using `\textcolor{white}` rather than `\color{white}`.

Comment: Just replace `\color{white}{cell2}` with `\textcolor{white}{cell2}`.

Comment: Aside: To assure maximum compatibility between the `xcolor` and `colortbl` packages, they shouldn’t be loaded independently from each other. Instead, do run `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`.